Next js set query param. Why this way?
next docs and other answers in google recomends change query params like this
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  function handleFilter(title, value) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
    params.set(title, value);
    router.replace(`${pathname}?${params}`, { scroll: false });
  
  }

But this way it works too:
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  function handleFilter(title, value) {
   router.replace(`${pathname}?${title}=${value}`, { scroll: false });
  }

why is it recommended everywhere to use this complex method and not just router.replace()?
Both methods are working and i don't see any difference

See what happens in both methods if either title or value contain e.g. ? or & or = characters. Or if the page already has other query parameters.

"i don't see any difference" ... for your input. If your path is already e.g. /.../?color=purple&size=xl, you're not going to have a great time.

The recommended way looks significantly cleaner to me and easier to understand to me. Second way looks like you could easily mess up with a typo or put something in the wrong place. It may be more lines of code but you can have a glance and immediately understand what's going on, with the other way yes it's quick to understand but when it's extended and more gets added it will look awful and be hard to read without comments. Add another 10 params (assuming this is for filters) and you might see what I mean

Basically in the first method, you are first preserving the state and then updating only specific(title) values. In the second method, you are just setting the new query string without preserving the state.
